# Can't find a guide about how to setup Django+Auth0+Graphene

Tags: django, auth0, graphene-django

I've been trying to setup my graphene API with Auth0 but I can't make it work.

I found similar questions like this: [Auth0 - Django and Graphene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947410/auth0-django-and-graphene) but yet unanswered.

I'd like to get some guidance about how to setup this 3 things together. Maybe pointing me out with a link?